# Simple Log to File example for django 1.3+

Tags: django, django-settings

The release notes say:

> Django 1.3 adds framework-level
>   support for Python’s logging module.

That's nice. I'd like to take advantage of that.  Unfortunately [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/) doesn't hand it all to me on a silver platter in the form of complete working example code which demonstrates how simple and valuable this is.

How do I set up this funky new feature such that I can pepper my code with

```
logging.debug('really awesome stuff dude: %s' % somevar)
```

and see the file "/tmp/application.log" fill up with

```
18:31:59 Apr 21 2011 awesome stuff dude: foobar
18:32:00 Apr 21 2011 awesome stuff dude: foobar
18:32:01 Apr 21 2011 awesome stuff dude: foobar
```

What's the difference between the default Python logging and this 'framework-level support'?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I truly love this so much here is your working example! Seriously this is awesome!

Start by putting this in your `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': SITE_ROOT + "/logfile",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Now what does all of this mean?

1. Formaters I like it to come out as the same style as ./manage.py runserver
2. Handlers - I want two logs - a debug text file, and an info console.  This allows me to really dig in (if needed) and look at a text file to see what happens under the hood.
3. Loggers - Here is where we nail down what we want to log.  In general django gets WARN and above - the exception (hence propagate) is the backends where I love to see the SQL calls since they can get crazy..  Last is my app were I have two handlers and push everything to  it.

Now how do I enable MYAPP to use it...

Per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#using-logging) put this at the top of your files (views.py)..

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then to get something out do this.

```
log.debug("Hey there it works!!")
log.info("Hey there it works!!")
log.warn("Hey there it works!!")
log.error("Hey there it works!!")
```

Log levels are explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#making-logging-calls) and for pure python [here](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

Comment: i followed the above steps. file is created but nothing is written to it. pleas help

Comment: @InternalServerError you need to replace MYAPP with the name of your app in the loggers section.

Comment: Note: you don't need everything from the above snippet if all you want to do is add logging to files. Just add the "logfile" handler and the "MYAPP" logger.

Comment: You bet!  Replace 'MYAPP' with ''

Comment: just in case 'MYAPP' is the name of the folder that contains settings.py

Comment: I did this it works fine in views.py but I have another folder within the same project it doesnt work.
Can you help me please?

Comment: For clarification, whatever you call the logger in `settings.py`, i.e. `MYAPP` in this example, also has be the parameter in the call to `logging.getLogger`. Therefore, if your project contains many self-contained apps and you want them to use a common logger you need to use `logging.getLogger('MYAPP')` instead of `logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Blank file is created. please suggest any solution.

Comment: Blank files are created in debug=True mode, locally.

Comment: This works great. Had to use 'class': 'logging.NullHandler' because 'django.utils.log.NullHandler' is no longer valid, but the rest worked for me in 1.11

Comment: this solution must be DEPRECATED because it does not work at all

Answer (score 5):

Based partially on the logging config suggested by rh0dium and [some more research](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1124) I did myself, I started assembling an example Django project with nice logging defaults – [fail-nicely-django](https://github.com/metakermit/fail-nicely-django).

Sample logfile output:

```
2016-04-05 22:12:32,984 [Thread-1    ] [INFO ] [djangoproject.logger]  This is a manually logged INFO string.
2016-04-05 22:12:32,984 [Thread-1    ] [DEBUG] [djangoproject.logger]  This is a manually logged DEBUG string.
2016-04-05 22:12:32,984 [Thread-1    ] [ERROR] [django.request      ]  Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kermit/.virtualenvs/fail-nicely-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/kermit/.virtualenvs/fail-nicely-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kermit/projekti/git/fail-nicely-django/djangoproject/brokenapp/views.py", line 12, in brokenview
    raise Exception('This is an exception raised in a view.')
Exception: This is an exception raised in a view.
```

The detailed usage is explained in the [README](https://github.com/metakermit/fail-nicely-django#fail-nicely-django), but essentially, you copy the [logger](https://github.com/metakermit/fail-nicely-django/blob/master/djangoproject/djangoproject/logger.py) module to your Django project and add `from .logger import LOGGING` at the bottom of your *settings.py*.