# Possible to log Django development server using cmd ">>"?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Is it possible to output Django's runserver output into a text file? such as:

`python manage.py runserver>>Log.txt`?

Comment: Do you mean `>>` instead of `<<`?

Comment: You can also use [getsentry.com](http://getsentry.com/) which will capture all logging and provide a nice interface for you to search/filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django uses python [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module and you can [configure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#an-example) it in your `settings.py` to output into file.

[Example for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739830/simple-log-to-file-example-for-django-1-3)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Im still newbie when it comes to Django. The help is very much appreciated and your check-mark is on the way ^.^.

Comment: @San4ez. No. Django uses the logging module. Not the Django development server. See here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563706/logging-django-request-to-file-instead-of-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563706/logging-django-request-to-file-instead-of-console)

Comment: For future visitors: Django `runserver` has used the `logging` module since version 1.10. Previously, logging from `runserver` was written to `sys.stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding following lines into `settings.py`.
This will both write a log file in `DEBUG` level and also display on console in `INFO` level.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': /path/to/django/debug.log,
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Please also have a look [Django documentaton](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/) for additional information.