# Logging django.request to file instead of console

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to configure my django `settings.py` to properly use the python logging facility but I've stumbled upon a rather strange problem:

Even after reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-request), I simply can't find out how to redirect the console printed debug request lines from Django to a file I've specified; Below is part of my logging configuration.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    }
    'handlers': {
        'file_http': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': r'C:\mysystem-http.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file_http'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        }
    }
}
```

I keep seeing my console print line of the following format:

`[19/Dec/2014 11:48:03] "POST /api/v1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10`

How may I redirect these to a file using the logging facility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for the record: if you have a multiprocess setup, logging to a file might not be such a good idea, cf https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Answer (score 6):

`manage.py runserver` is not using logging system for messages like `[19/Dec/2014 11:48:03] "POST /api/v1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10`. Instead of this, runserver uses sys.stderr (and sys.stdout for others messages). If you really need to redirect this to file you can override sys.stderr settings.py. Example - logging sys.stderr to file and console:

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.console = sys.stderr
        self.file = open("runserver.log", "a", 0)

    def write(self, msg):
        self.console.write(msg)
        self.file.write(msg)

sys.stderr = Logger()
```

In write method you can use logging system to handle this by LOGGING settings as well.

Update:

In Django 1.10, runserver output goes through logging:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#runserver-output-goes-through-logging

Comment: How is this better then a bash redirect?

Comment: Simple, it's not better (maybe one reason for this is that you can log to file + console in the same time and add filter/formaters etc.).

Answer (score 3):

These outputs are handled by your HTTP server (WSGIServer from the standard library if running in dev mode).

The configuration of your `settings.py` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Right. So, is there a way to redirect that output of that library using the logging facility?

Comment: It depends on your stack.

Answer (score 0):

[@dikamilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353215/dikamilo)'s answer is correct.

Prior to Django 1.10, `manage.py runserver` ran Django's own [WSGIServer](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L108) implementation, which logged to sys.stderr.

Adding the following code to `settings.py` will monkey patch the WSGIRequestHandler used by `runserver` so that all requests are logged via the logging module with the name `django.server` in order to roughly mimic the behaviour of Django 1.10+.

```py
###############################################################################
# SUPER-JANK PATCH FOR DJANGO RUNSERVER LOGGING PRIOR TO VERSION 1.10
###############################################################################
#
# Add this to settings.py
#
import logging
from django.core.servers.basehttp import WSGIRequestHandler
logger = logging.getLogger('django.server')
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    # Don't bother logging requests for admin images or the favicon.
    if self.path.startswith(self.admin_static_prefix) or self.path == '/favicon.ico':
        return
    msg = format % args
    if args[1][0] in ['1', '4', '5']:
        logger.warn(msg)
    else:
        logger.info(msg)

WSGIRequestHandler.log_message = log_message
```

It replaces the [log_message](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L142) method, which is responsible for actually writing to `stderr`.

After adding this patch, you can configure logging as you normally would via `LOGGING` in `settings.py`.