# Enable Django logging also if DEBUG is True

Tags: django, django-settings

By reading the official django documentation I haven't understood much about it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

I would like to enable logging also if **DEBUG** in settings.py is set to **True**.
I would like the errors to be logged in a file.

How to do that?

These are the default django settings for logging which I currently have now:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

**PS:**
I'm using Apache + mod_wsgi in my development environment because I use a development machine which i access remotely on my LAN, this means i'm not using the django development server and I can't see the console log messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django logging is not disabled by default in either DEBUG mode unless you have set it to.

Add below to your `handlers` part of `LOGGING`

```
'file':
        {
            'level':
                'INFO',
            'class':
                'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter':
                'verbose',
            'filename':
                'myapp.log'

        }
```

It will log to `myapp.log` file in your project root. You can specify a complete path.

And add a formatters field to the Logging dict

```
'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format':
                '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of working settings inspired by [Simple Log to File example for django 1.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739830/simple-log-to-file-example-for-django-1-3)

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': SITE_ROOT + "/debug.log",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'custom',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        #'django': {
        #    'handlers':['logfile'],
        #    'level':'DEBUG',
        #    'propagate': True,
        #},
        #'django.request': {
        #    'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'logfile'],
        #    'level': 'DEBUG',
        #    'propagate': True,
        #},
        'nodeshot.core.mailing': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'custom': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s\n%(message)s'
        },
    },
}
```