# Logging events in django application

Tags: python, django

I need to log some business events in my Django 1.4 application. For example, when user send a refferal email, or user makes a purchase. And so on. This event log will be used for some busness analytics.
Is there any best practisies for doing this in e-commercial applications? May be a service or django module? I've never developed such systems before and I need some advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you're talking about using the built-in but just for give another option, I usually use a model to store log action in some e-commerce pages, such as:

```
class MyLog(models.Model):
    LOG_ACTIONS = (
        ('login', 'User logged in'),
        ('delete_object', 'User delete object'),
        ('create_object', 'User create object'),
        ('buy_object', 'User buy object'),
        #   ...     ...     ...
        # Whatever you need here
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='login', choices=LOG_ACTIONS, verbose_name= 'action')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='date')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dt']
        verbose_name = 'Action log'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Actions log'
```

---

The example is simplified, you can use as many fields as you need and as many log actions as you need.

So when you do any action that have to be in the log, just create an object for MyLog, and when you want to get all log actions, just get MyLog objects, and  you can filter them by date, user or any field you put in there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Looks like this is the best way to do logging. I've thought about something like this. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I usually choose this option because I can customize the log in function of the project I'm working on.

Comment: How do I hook this up to a view. Assuming I upload a file from a view, it should be added to the log?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a different question, I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're looking for

Comment: Do you think it will be better to ask this as a separate question? If, no you can let me know how to proceed, then I continue researching.

Comment: If you want we can chat about it, or you can ask a separate question and I will try to answer you there

Comment: Maybe we chat since I am not entirely sure of how to phrase the question.

Comment: Check this room out http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121643/django-logging-doubts

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in logging app. Check the 1.4 docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/

Comment: Yes, I know about it. I thought there any more specific application.
Have you ever used django logger for tracking users activity?

Comment: [Use the logger like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739830/simple-log-to-file-example-for-django-1-3)