# Simple log to console in Django 1.7.11

Tags: python, django

I've been breaking my head over creating a simple logfile within my django application. I've tried applying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739830/simple-log-to-file-example-for-django-1-3), as well as the examples on the docs, but it simply doesn't seem to work and I don't know what is going wrong.

My current logfile, second example straight from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

The docs states the following:

> "this config only sends messages of level INFO or higher to the console"

In my understanding, if I were to place this into my `home.view.py` file...

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug("Hey there it works!!")
log.info("Hey there it works!!")
log.warn("Hey there it works!!")
log.error("Hey there it works!!")
```

...i  should get the `info`, the `warn` and the `error` message printed to my console, whenever a call is made to `home.views.py`, which I thought happens when I visit the correct url.

This appears to be false. It seems however that only `warn` and `error` is printed, and only when I run `manage.py collectstatic`.

```
WARNING:home.views:Hey there it works!!
ERROR:home.views:Hey there it works!!
```

I want to receive the log messages in console, whenever I visit a webpage that's rendered from `home.views.py`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')
```

First tries to get the environment variable if set. If not set then it defaults to the second argument. Its possible `DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL` is set to something higher than INFO.

To test this hypothesis run the following in your environment.

```
echo $DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL
```

Make sure its either 1. not set, or 2. set to INFO

```
export DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
```

Comment: Running the `echo` returns nothing. Running `env = os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL','INFO')` returns 'INFO'. It appears it is not set.